# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies[App Name]

Tags: console, google-play-services

I am trying to publish my official app to google play multiple times. But has been rejected multiple times due to invalid privacy policies. I don't know exactly where I am going wrong in the privacy policy.

> Privacy Policy URL:
> https://www.univision.solutions/app-privacy-policy
>
> Issue found: Invalid privacy policy Your app’s privacy policy does not
> meet necessary policy requirements. Under the User Data policy, you
> must link to a privacy policy on your app's store listing page and
> within your app. Apps that do not access any personal and sensitive
> user data must still submit a privacy policy.
>
> Please add or update your privacy policy, and make sure it is
> available on an active URL (no PDFs), is non-editable, applies to your
> app, and specifically covers user privacy.
>
> Please review the following compliance checklist for privacy policies.
> Your privacy policy must:
>
> Be linked on your app’s store listing page in Play Console and within
> the app itself. Hold reference to the entity (for example, developer,
> company) named in the app’s Google Play listing or the app. Include a
> clear labeling as a privacy policy. Include a privacy point of contact
> or a mechanism to submit inquiries. Be readable in a standard browser
> without any plug-ins or special handlers (no PDFs). Be available on an
> active, publicly accessible and non-geofenced URL. Be non-editable.
> Comprehensively disclose how your app accesses, collects, uses, and
> shares user data. This must include: Disclosing the types of personal
> and sensitive user data your app accesses, collects, uses, and shares;
> and any parties with which any personal or sensitive user data is
> shared. Secure data handling procedures for personal and sensitive
> user data. Developer’s data retention and deletion policy. Issue
> details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> Privacy policy: "URL provided
> https://www.univision.solutions/app-privacy-policy does not link to a
> valid privacy policy page" About the Privacy policy in Google Play
> User Data policy Please provide a valid privacy policy link even if
> your app does not collect any personal and sensitive user data.
> Starting August 22, 2022, your app must be in compliance with this
> policy or app updates will be rejected. Review the policy linked below
> for all the requirements of a privacy policy.
>
> [image]

Comment: @KJ thanks for Editing and formatting the post.

Comment: @James Z Thank you for formatting